# How to make a CSS change smooth?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image in grayscale, so when use jQuery mouseenter it changes to the colored version.
This is my code...

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.items', function() {
        img = $(this).data('img');
        img2 = img.replace(".", "C.");
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(img/" + img2 + ")");
    }).on('mouseleave', '.items', function() {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(img/" + img + ")");
    }); 
});
```

It works by the way... the problem is that this "transition/change" is not in a smooth way, it came out like when a page is refreshed page like a "spark". So is not a good way of presentation.
Can anyone tell me what can i do to fix this??
Thanx...

Comment: Use a css sprite. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use them. My favourite is by Chris Coyer. CSS animations are far less processor intensive than javaScript so your site will be faster too.

Comment: you mean like this: 

transition: all .4s ease-in-out; or else?

Comment: instead of using the css method, use addClass and removeClass and have the class have css like Zoidberg said

Comment: the problem is that i can't use a class because the background images load dinamycally... they have load inline style in a handlebars template...

Answer (score 0):

Could get smooth transition between images many different ways, here's three...

**Option 1: jQuery `on` delegation for hovering (for dynamically loaded elements)**

<kbd>[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/Bjzzh/3/)</kbd>

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img-transition bw"></div>
    <div class="img-transition color"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '#container', function() {
    $('.color', this).fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', '#container', function() {
    $('.color', this).fadeOut();
});
```

---

**Option 2: jQuery `hover` event solution (for *not* dynamically loaded elements)**

<kbd>[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/Bjzzh/1/)</kbd>

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img-transition bw"></div>
    <div class="img-transition color"></div>
</div>
```

```
var $container = $('#container'),
    $color = $('.color');

$container.hover(function() { // mouseover
    $color.fadeIn();
}, function() { // mouseout
    $color.fadeOut();
});
```

---

**Option 3: CSS3 [transition](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property) property**

<kbd>[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/92CKq/2/)</kbd>

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img-transition bw"></div>
    <div class="img-transition color"></div>
</div>
```

```
.color{
    background-position:-47px -47px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 400ms linear;
}
.color:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

`transition` has good [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fadeIn-fadeOut way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cont">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
   <img class="color" src="http://placehold.it/350x350/00adee/ff5400" />
</div>`
```

**CSS**

```
.cont {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
.cont .color {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;  
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cont', function(){
        $('img.color', $(this)).fadeIn(1000);

    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('img.color', $(this)).fadeOut(1000)
    }) 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwgB7/